# Where are Perl modules installed in Ubuntu?

Tags: perl, ubuntu, module

In Windows, Perl modules are installed in `C:/Perl64/site/lib/`. What is the corresponding location in an Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 15):

To find out where a module is installed, you can use:

```
perl -E'use Some::Module; say $INC{"Some/Module.pm"};'
```

You can find out where `perl` will look (`@INC`) using

```
perl -V    # Uppercase "V"
```

or

```
perl -E'say for @INC'
```

I don't know why you'd want to know, so I'm not quite sure what you are actually looking for. A more detailed question could lead to a better answer.

Comment: From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches): `-E` behaves just like `-e`, except that it implicitly enables all optional [features](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).  For ex: feature `say`

Comment: You might like the -M command line option. `perl -MSome::Module -E'say $INC{"Some/Module.pm"};'`

Comment: On Ubuntu this appears to be `/usr/share/perl5`. (This may save someone some time.)

Comment: @Nathan Osman, No, the equivalent directory (the site lib) for the distro-installed Perl on Ubuntu 12 is actually `/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2`. For Ubuntu 14, it's `/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2`. (Obtained using ` perl -V:installsitelib`.) But those are just one of many directories a module can be installed in.

Answer (score 7):

The location of the Perl libraries depends entirely on the installation. The folders that Perl searches to load a library are stored in the `@INC` array, which you can display using

```
perl -E "say for @INC"
```

On my installation this outputs

```
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib
C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
C:/strawberry/perl/lib
.
```

Answer (score 4):

`perldoc` can tell you where any particular module is installed with its `-l` (lowercase ell) switch:

```
% perldoc -l Module::Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll find them in `/usr/lib/perl/{VERSION}/` as well as `/usr/lib64/perl/{VERSION}/`.

`{VERSION}` corresponding to the version of Perl. You can get it with `perl --version`.